# Would Sabre make a good first stage engine for a hypothetical 2-stage design?

Tags: reuse, specific-impulse, ssto, sabre-engine

Sabre is usually described in the context of the Skylon SSTO design but, would it make more sense to use such engines for the first stage of a two stage design?

Basically, would the air breathing capability of Sabre be a worthwhile advantage over a pure rocket to perform the launch to the upper atmosphere phase in a staged design.

(Presuming the full recovery of the mooted Sabre first stage, here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Reaction Engines Ltd (REL) web site has [this](https://www.reactionengines.co.uk/sabre/flight-applications) to say:

"The resulting increased system performance enables aircraft-like horizontal take-off and landing operations, which reduce cost, infrastructure, and mission timelines while increasing responsiveness and system reusability. SABRE class engines are applicable in both multi-stage and single-stage architectures."

REL have been distancing themselves from SSTO as the first application for several years - you'll be hard pressed to find any mention of Skylon on their site now. A 30th Anniversary tweet showed a badge/patch including their current TSTO concept -- complete with (the other sort of) aerospike:

[image: TSTO 30 years]

They have participated in a number of studies using SABRE engines as the first stage, including those with the Air Force Research Laboratories
[image: AFRL SABRE TSTO fully reusable]

and Paris University/CNES

[image: SABRE TSTO options]

Latest REL TSTO concept :
[image: REL TSTO concept 2019]